# angularjs where to start service

Tags: angularjs, cordova, service

I want to start a service in angularjs in function app.run like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout, MessagesService) {
  if(!MessagesService.isRunning()){
    MessagesService.startService();
  }
}
```

the problem is that app.run is called twice, and even if messageservice was started already, it runs another instance of a service... service should be singleton so I don't understand what is happening. Or maybe this is a bad function to start a service in?

///edited
I paste whole app.run

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout, AuthenticationService, FlashService, MessagesService, ContactsService) {


  if(!MessagesService.isRunning()){
    MessagesService.startService();
  }

  if(!ContactsService.isRunning()){
    ContactsService.startService();
  }

  $rootScope.newContactReq = 0;
  $rootScope.newMsgCount = 0;
  var routesThatNotRequireAuth = ['/login','/register'];

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    if(!_(routesThatNotRequireAuth).contains($location.path())) {
      if(!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()){
        $location.path('/login');
        FlashService.show("Please log in to continue.");
      }
    }
  });

  $rootScope.$watch(function() { 
    return $location.path(); 
  },
  function(a){  
    if(!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      $rootScope.isUserAuth = 0;
    }
    else{
      $rootScope.isUserAuth = 1;
    }
  });


});
```

even when I do something like

```
if($rootScope.service === undefined)
$rootScope.service = 1;
```

it than runs the app.run for second time and $rootScope.service is undefined again...

Comment: yep that's strange,and no module.run is exactly where you should bootstrap some services.Can you paste more code here?

Comment: I edited question and put more code...